# How to use generics instead of inheritance to have multiple versions of something

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

In your company, say you have the following code:

```
public abstract Phone
{
    public int PhoneID {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}

public CustomerPhone : Phone
{
    public int CustomerID {get;set;}
}

public AccountPhone : Phone
{
    public int AccountID {get;set;}
}
```

What this is supposed to mean is we have multiple types of phones, some are customer phones, some are account phones, etc...

The question is "is this possible, and if so then how?" It seems it would be easiest to just have a generic Phone class into which you can plug a Type and it would then just use that Type's information(AccountID or CustomerID) to use when needed. I'm also checking to see if this is possible WITHOUT DI(whether via constructor, method, or property.)

What I have in my head would look something like this:

```
public interface IUsePhone
{
    int GetOwnerID();
}

public class Phone<T> where T : IUsePhone
{
    //all of Phone's properties from above.

    public int GetOwnerID()
    {
        //return T or item or something's GetOwnerID();
    }
}

public class Account : IUsePhone
{
    private int _accountID;

    //other Account members, including an AccountID property.

    public int GetOwnerID()
    {
        return _accountID;
    }   

    public Phone<Account> Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IUsePhone
{
    private int _customerID;

    //other Customer members, including an CustomerID property.

    public int GetOwnerID()
    {
        return _customerID;
    }

    public Phone<Customer> Phone { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't compile because Phone's GetOwnerID() doesn't currently have any way to return it's owner's GetOwnerID() result. I would hope the end result from the client perspective could look something like this:

```
Account myAccount = new Account();
myAccount.AccountID = 10;

int ownerID = myAccount.Phone.GetOwnerID(); //this would return 10.
```

Comment: Compilation and run-time are being confused. Given lack of something better, this can be made to compile with `return default(T)`, although that is not very useful. Consider if there was a `SetPhone(IUsePhone ..)` method. Note that `Account/Customer` do not unify to `Phone<T>` even if they do at `IUsePhone`.

Comment: This may sound silly, and there might not actually be a way to do what I'm talking about. I was hoping to not have to use either reflection or dependency injection like you mention(via SetPhone method.) The more I think of it, the more impossible it seems once you take those two options away, but I know there are some really smart people out there so I figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: This looks like a job for the Factory Pattern (http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to ask yourself why you want to do this.

If you really want a bunch of different types, all of which have the `Phone` contract fulfilled, you are better off with an interface, plus perhaps an abstract base implementation:

```
public interface IPhone
{
    int PhoneID {get;set;}
    string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}

public abstract AbstractPhoneBase : IPhone
{
    public int PhoneID {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}

public CustomerPhone : AbstractPhoneBase
{
    public int CustomerID {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what we have now in our design. What I was doing research on is to see if we could get away from having to have a "CustomerPhone" and a "SomeOtherTypePhone" because ALL of them are the exact same minus the NAME of the owner id. i.e. CustomerID in CustomerPhone and SomeOtherTypeID in SomeOtherTypePhone.

Comment: If that is truly the case, add a property `string AdditionalIdDescripton` and make the generic property `string AdditionalId` or whatever applies in your detailed use case.   If you need to map those values to a small closed set, you can use an `enum` instead of a string.

Comment: @f0x Be very, very careful with humor on SO.   The community is notoriously intolerant of that sort of thing.

Comment: Why not refactor your code and get rid different names of Id ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan That is basically what I was suggestion with the `AdditionalIdDescription` comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is fine - just missing the constructor that takes in the instance of the owner implementing IUsePhone (Account, Customer, etc).

Try adding this to your `Phone<T>` class.

```
    public IUsePhone Owner { get; private set; }

    public Phone(T owner)
    {
        this.Owner = owner;
    }

    public int GetOwnerID()
    {
        return this.Owner.GetOwnerID();
    }
```

NOTE: In your example, don't forget you will have to set the Phone property before `myAccount.Phone.GetOwnerID();` can be called.

If you are doing it this way I would go down the abstract base class route already suggested and set the Phone in a base method along the lines of:

```
public virtual void SetPhoneNumber<T>(string number)
    {
        this.Phone = new Phone<T>(this);
        this.Phone.Number = number;
    }
```

So your useage would end up looking like this:

```
    Account myAccount = new Account();
    myAccount.AccountID = 10;

    myAccount.SetPhoneNumber("123456");

    int ownerID = myAccount.Phone.GetOwnerID(); // this would return 10.
```